# rails 3 JqTree Object has no method tree

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jqtree

I'm using rails 3.2 with jquery-rails 2.0.2 and jqtree-rails (0.1.5.0)

The included javascript files looks like this in my html page:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.alerts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.cookie.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.forms.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.section.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tree.jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/lib/namespace.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.checkbox-toggler.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.dropdown-menu.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/components/jquery.aa.table-checkbox-toggler.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/pages/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/pages/batch_actions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript">      </script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin/base.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_admin.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/domains.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/guest_books.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

I have copied the first example given on the site of jqtree, but I have this javascipt error:
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getOwnPropertyNames'

If some know how to fix it, it would be great! thanks

Comment: try https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/ .. not sure but may help

Comment: The error should have more information about the line/script is failing. Please include the complete error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was tu upgrade jquery. I was working with an old version.

With the last version of jquery everything works fine.